# How can I activate "Use Visual Studio Development Server" options on Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, virtual-path, aspnet-development-server

I want to clear Solution **Virtual Path** on *Visual Studio 2013* but I can't find "**Use Visual Studio Development Server**" options when right click on Solution like in *Visual Studio 2012*. Can you help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short **It's been discontinued**

Your only option now is to use IIS Express, or normal IIS.

Here are [some](http://caniruddha.wordpress.com/2013/09/10/visual-studio-development-server-discontinued-in-the-visual-studio-2013-preview/) [sources](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/visual-studio-2013-remove-development-server-aka-cassini) backing it up.